# Mounting unix to synology nas and special characters

Tags: ubuntu, fstab, nas, synology

I'm trying to mount my Synology NAS to Ubuntu with fstab, and I have some folders on the NAS containing '!' in the folder name, as well as spaces.
The spaces I found out that I can escape with \040, but what about the ! (exclamation mark)? I've searched but haven't found any answer yet.

This is a part of my fstab filer right now;

```
192.168.1.102:/volume1/Disk2/!Film\040-\040480p nfs auto 0 0
192.168.1.102:/volume1/Disk2/!Film\040-\040720p nfs auto 0 0
192.168.1.102:/volume1/Disk2/!Film\040-\0401080p nfs auto 0 0
192.168.1.102:/volume1/Disk2/!Film\040-\040Barn nfs auto 0 0
192.168.1.102:/volume1/Disk2/!Film\040-\040Barn\040-\040Temp nfs auto 0 0
192.168.1.102:/volume1/Disk2/!Film\040-\040Barn\040-\040Disneynfs auto 0 0
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L!  What methods of escaping have you tried so far?  `\!`?  `\041`?

Comment: tried \!, not working. Haven't tried \041 because I couldn't find any list that explained all substitutions for special characters. But thanx, I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

I should add \041 and put the path as well, this worked:

```
 192.168.1.102:/volume1/Disk2/!Film\040-\040480p /media/movies
```